Problem in HTREE directory inode
I have error in operating system Oracle Linux
cannot startup and got this error
Problem in HTREE directory inode 

please see the image error of the system when reboot :

what is the error reason and how to fix the error I am not LINUX administrator
and thank you in advance

Enter your root password to log in to the emergency shell. In the emergency shell run
fsck /dev/vg00/lv07

It may present you with a list of questions. If so, you will generally answer Yes. Note that there is a risk of data loss, as the file system is in a unclean state.
When you're done, press Ctrl-d to exit and reboot.
If you don't have the root password or are not the system administrator, the best path forward is to contact the administrator and request assistance.

From the screenshot it seems as if the user does not know the root password. They also say they’re not an administrator on this system.

I read it a bit differently; as that they are inexperienced as administrators. But once I read your comment I agree with you; that may very well be the case.

@vidarlo thank you for your answer I have root password but when I type it its not proceed and go back to same line , if there is data loss risk I will ask for assistance from administrator

You must boot from some other medium. You cannot fsck a disk if ANY of it's partitions is in use (mounted or swap).
Boot from your install medium in "Try out" mode, or a Live USB. Run fsck from there, or run gparted.
Downvoters: Be aware that the disk's metadata (block allocation tables, specifically) are kept in RAM when a partition is mounted, and periodically written back to the disk. fsck reads the (obsolete) metadata from the disk, and works with it. Whichever one (system or fsck) writes the metadata first will have it overwriitten by the other. It's a standard CompSci problem - independant processes both thinking they have exclusive access to the same data, when they don't.

This is more or less plain wrong. You don't have to boot from a live medium; initrd images means that the volume is not mounted (or mounted Read Only) when you log in to the emergency shell.
